# How to Separate emails in CC by HTMl or javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I wrote a web application with c# and Asp.Net to send an emails to multi persons
and I can send email to and cc (just one in the cc)
but I can't send to multi. 
Another I can't put multi emails in the text box by HTML or JavaScript
as the Tags below.

Comment: please reformat your question

Comment: Please include some code with your question, so that others may be able to help you with the issues